# PowerPoint VBA - OnSlideShowPageChange not based on slide number

Tags: vba, powerpoint

So far I have been using this:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal objWindow As SlideShowWindow)
'    MsgBox objWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
    If objWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex = 10 Then Call ReadMyFile1
End Sub
```

But every time I insert a slide, the `SlideIndex` changes and I have to change the code. Is there a better way?

I am using `OnSlideShowPageChange` as the equivalent of `Form_Load` but I need to specify the slide index.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of .SlideIndex, use .SlideID

.SlideIndex returns the ordinal number of the slide within the presentation; change the order of slides and the ordinal number will change, as you've seen.

.SlideID is a Long that's assigned to the slide at the time it's created and never changes, even if the slides are re-ordered.

Well.  Almost never changes.  If you insert a slide into a different presentation, it'll get a new .SlideID

If that promises to be an issue, you'll probably need to add a tag to the slide, which you can do in the Immediate window of the IDE:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(x).Tags.Add "Tagname", "TagValue"
```

where X is the .SlideIndex, and Tagname and TagValue are any strings you like.

Then change your existing routine to something like this {aircode}

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal objWindow As SlideShowWindow)
    If objWindow.View.Slide.Tags("Tagname") = "TagValue" Then Call ReadMyFile1
    ' If there's no tag on the slide, querying .Tags("any string") will return a blank; 
    ' no need for error handling here
End Sub
```

Comment: This is nice. Why can't we see the Tag and SlideID properties of a Slide like we can see of VBA objects? It shows only 4 properties of a Slide.

Comment: See it where? Tags shows up as a property Slide objects in the object browser and in Intellisense here, though if you're using a Mac, the VBA IDE might not give you that much help.